# Mouseover() event for multiple divs from a class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three divs in one line, aligned with the css prop "display: table-cell":

```
<div id="divMaster" width="1000" height="1000">
    <div id="divMenu1" class="divMenu"> Opción 1 </div>     
    <div id="divMenu2" class="divMenu"> Opción 2 </div>
    <div id="divMenu3" class="divMenu"> Opción 3 </div>
</div>
```

Then I have this problem trying to animate one single div when mouse is passing over.
I'm trying this:

```
$(".divMenu").mouseover(function()
{
    target = "#" + $(this).attr("ID");
    $(target).stop(true, false);
    $(target).animate({opacity: '+=' + (parseFloat(oFin) - parseFloat($(target).css("opacity"))) + '',  height: '+=' + (parseFloat(hFin) - parseFloat($(target).css("height"))) + ''}, {duration: 1000, easing: "easeOutCirc"});
});

$(".divMenu").mouseleave(function()
{
    target = "#" + $(this).attr("ID");
    $(target).stop(true, false);
    $(target).animate({opacity: '-=' + (parseFloat($(target).css("opacity")) - parseFloat(oIni)) + '', height: '-=' + (parseFloat($(target).css("height")) - parseFloat(hIni)) + ''}, {duration: 1000, easing: "easeOutCirc"});     
});
```

What really happens with this code is that every div from the class do the animation.
As I said before: what I'm trying to do is to animate a single div when mouse enters in an element from the class.

**What I already tried:**

- Using "startswith" identifier instead of using ".divMenu".
- Using delegate instead of mouseover and mouseleave events.

NOTE: "oFin", "hFin", etc. are just constants.

Comment: Create a fiddle for us... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Why are you looking up the id and reselecting the element when you already have the element?

Comment: For further questions, if it's something web related, create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). And maintain some code quality, your current `.animate` line is 223 characters long, which is way to much. A simple rule: if it doesn't fit in code block (meaning horizontal scrollbar appears) it's probably too long. There are *rare* exceptions.

Comment: epascarello: I tried to do it without setting that "target" variable, just using 'this'. Here is a fiddle of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/yn8j9ryp/ . As you can see: no results.

Answer (score 0):

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yh01drcn/)

```
    $(".divMenu").mouseover(function()
{
  $( this ).animate({
    fontSize: "50",
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't know if you didn't add the code to the `mouseout` on purpose, but [here's an updated JSFiddle with it](http://jsfiddle.net/yh01drcn/1/).

Comment: @aelieo The animation I'm using isn't the animation Bruno needs, therefor I showed him how to do it, and he can do it himself with the animaton he wants.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate the help. Here is a fiddle of the code that I have: http://jsfiddle.net/yn8j9ryp/ . The three divs are sliding down, but I want just one to slide down. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @BrunoMamani updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yn8j9ryp/1/ I removed display:table-cell, and changed it into float:left;

Comment: @Nick Amazing! Thank you man. I'll investigate what "float:left;" means, cause I have no idea :P Thank you again.

Comment: @BrunoMamani I used float:left; because it positioned the divs next to eachother, You can also use display:inline-block; etc. display:table-cell was the problem that gave the weird outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to put each divMenu within it's own divMaster.  That prevents the height from propagating across.

eg.

```
<div id="divMaster1" width="1000" height="1000">
    <div id="divMenu1" class="divMenu">Opción 1</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yn8j9ryp/3/